# Deploying Dash (python/plotly) app accessing AWS RDS on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, plotly-dash, pymysql

I've been attempting to deploy the below zip folder(files) in AWS Beanstalk.

```
Dashboard.zip:
|_ application.py
|_ requirements.txt
|_ AWSRDBInputs.py
```

The AWSRDBInputs.py is basically used to query tables in an AWS RD and store the query results in several dataframes. (using pymysql library)

The dataframes are then imported to the application.py file to process and generate graphs and tables - that are displayed on the dash app.[e.g.: from AWSInputs import df1,df2,df3]

However, after deploying this app I get a 502 Bad Gateway error. The app works fine locally. Are there additional steps/code I need to take/add before deploying this on beanstalk? Can someone please suggest possible fixes for this issue?